# powershell - trying to use split method to isolate the number "50" from the returned value "Free : 50"

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I hope my question doesn't annoy the ops for having broken some rule...certainly not my intention.

I have installed the DHCP role in Windows Server 2012 r2. After that, I have set up a scope using Powershell:

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Scope -name "ambito1" -StartRange 10.0.0.1 -EndRange 10.0.0.50  -SubnetMask 255.255.255.0
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is make a script which asks the user to insert an IP address falling within the scope's range which will be checked for availability by comparing it to those ip's returned by the *Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress* cmdlet.

In order to achieve this, I first need to know the total number of free ip's within the scope (to simplify things, I will keep all the ip's within the scope available) and somewhere down the line, pass that number to the -NumAddress parameter of the Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress cmdlet, so I can match the user's chosen ip with the corresponding one on the list of returned available ip's.

So if I write:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ScopeId 10.0.0.0 | Select-Object Free | Format-List
```

it returns:

```
Free : 50
```

...which is what I want...but my headaches begin when I try to split *Free : 50* in order to extract and store into a variable the number '50'. What I've done is store the result of the pipeline *Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ScopeId 10.0.0.0 | Select-Object Free | Format-List* into a variable and try to use *split* as a method or an operator to ultimately get my '50' out of the 'Free : 50' but it has proven impossible so far.

For instance, writing:

```
$a=Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ScopeId 10.0.0.0 | Select-Object Free | Format-List

$a.Split(" : ")
```

returns:

```
Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData
Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

instead of:

```
Free

50
```

P.D. I have an alternative script from someone else which works but it has a slightly different approach and I'm hell bent on getting my approach to work (i.e. using *split*).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the value you want:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ScopeId 10.0.0.0 | Select-Object -Expand Free
```

Don't use `Format-List` when you want to process the output.

Comment: You've achieved in the blink of an eye what I could not in 5 and a half hours...thank you so much !!

Comment: If manojlds answer solved your issue please mark it as so with the green check mark on the left hand side of his answer. Welcome to SO. @Guiri

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the property using dot notation on the command:

```
(Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ScopeId 10.0.0.0).Free
```

You can also store the result in a variable and use the dot notation to get at the property of the stored result:

```
$a=Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ScopeId 10.0.0.0 
$a.Free
```

The dot notation won't work on Powershell older than version 3 when there are multiple objects in the pipelive, in that case you would need to use manojlds's `-Expand` solution.

Comment: Wow...that's certainly new for me. Thanks !!